# How to make Windows scroll direction when using wacom consistent

Tags: windows-10, wacom-one

Sometimes when dragging the scrollbar using wacom pen to upper direction, it scrolled down, but sometimes it scrolled up (like 50:50 chance, but some software has consistent result but in right or wrong direction, like task manager or chrome). How to make it consistent up always up, down always down?